# Counting Polar Bears

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

My class is starting to work with generating functions, and I've been working
on a problem related to the counting of polar bears. Suppose that there is
this bar that polar bears really like to get drinks at, and the bartender has
been noticing a trend in the polar bears coming into his bar. Say at time 0,
there are no bears at the bar, at time 1, there are 3 bears at the bar, and for
every time $t \geq 2,$ The number of bears in the bar is equal to 5 times the 
number of bears in the bar at time $t-1$ plus the numbers of bears in the bar at
time $t-2$ I want to find a close form expression for $P_n$, which is the number
of bears in the bar at time $n.$ I get that I need to start this problem with
considering the generation function $P(x)$ and that formally $P_0 = 0,P_1 = 3$,
and $P_n = 5P_{n-1} + P_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 2.$ I'm wondering if it might be 
good to make $P_{n-1}$ and $P_{n-2}$ functions of the main
generating function $P(x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just solve the recurrence directly.
You have $P_{n+2} -5P_{n+1} -P_n = 0$, the eigenvalues are
the roots of $x^2-5x-1 = 0$ which we can compute as
${1 \over 2} (5 \pm \sqrt{29})$. Hence the
general solution is $P_n =  \left({5 + \sqrt{29} \over 2}\right)^n c_0 + \left({5 - \sqrt{29} \over 2}\right)^n c_1$ for some constants
$c_0,c_1$. Since $P_0 = 0$ we have $c_1 = -c_0$ and from $P_1 = 3$
we get $c_0 = {3 \over \sqrt{29}}$.

Hence $P_n = {3 \over \sqrt{29}} \left(\left({5 + \sqrt{29} \over 2}\right)^n - \left({5 - \sqrt{29} \over 2}\right)^n\right)$.

Comment: Very nice, you can arrive at the same closed form from the method of @gt6989b

Comment: @Sky: Yes, that would be the unilateral $z$-transform; but then you need to 'invert' the result to obtain the sequence $(P_0,P_1,...)$.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, define
$$
P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_n x^n
$$
and apply your identity:
$$
P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_n x^n
     = 3x + 5 \sum_{k=2}^\infty P_{n-1} x^n + \sum_{k=2}^\infty P_{n-2} x^n
$$
Notice that the last sum is
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty P_{n-2} x^n
 = x^2 \sum_{k=2}^\infty P_{n-2} x^{n-2}
 = x^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_n x^n
 = x^2 P(x)
$$

Can you transform the other sum and solve for $P(x)$?